# Best Practice thread handling

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Right now we are doing in our class multithreading and I'm learning from the slides from our teacher and from the internet.

We have to do a calculation (Standardization of Measurement Values) were each of the parts are Depending on the one before and I also have to use mutex for some specific calculation.

Right now I created for each method an extra thread and join it and do the same thing for the next one and so on.

Is there a better way, or a best practise to do it, right now it’s more like try and error (I'm not good at c++ and learning it but it’s a task in parallelisation)?

I'll paste the code here at the and, so it's understandable what i do... sorry for the messy code it’s not finished yet but it's working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;
//global variables because of quick and dirty...

vector<float> x = {-10.2, -8.0, 0.5, 5.9, 3.5, 22.7, 15.0, -1.8, -3.1, 7.7, 11.2, 7.9, -3.3,
                   -1.6, 15.3, 22.6, 3.6, 5.7, 2.0, -18.2, -27.5, 23.1, 18.1, 9.7, 25.8};
float mf;
float sf;
float oDN; //oDN= one divided by N
atomic<int> getXMf(0);
atomic<int> getXSf(0);
atomic<int> getXZ(0);

void calcMf() {
    for (getXMf; getXMf <= x.size(); getXMf++) {
        mf += oDN * x[getXMf];
    }
}
void calcSf() {
    for (getXSf; getXSf <= x.size(); getXSf++) {
        sf += oDN * (fabsf(x[getXSf] - mf));
    }
}
int main() {
    //initial args
    thread mythread
    vector<thread> worker1;
    vector<thread> worker2;
    vector<thread> worker3;
    float getSizeofX = x.size();
    oDN = 1 / getSizeofX;
    //
    //first worker doing calcMF and pushing to a vector
    for (int i = 0; i < mythread.hardware_concurrency(); ++i) {
        worker1.push_back(thread(&calcMf)
        );
    }
    //call first threads and join em;
    for (thread &ths: worker1) {
        ths.join();
    }

    //first worker doing calcMF and pushing to a vector
    for (int i = 0; i < mythread.hardware_concurrency(); ++i) {
        worker2.push_back(thread(&calcSf)
        );
    }
    //call second threads and join em;
    for (thread &ths: worker2) {
        ths.join();
    }

    cout << "mf: " << mf << endl;
    cout << "sf: " << sf << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`#include <algorithm>` and `atomic<int> getXZ(0);` not used yet
Edit: fixed stupid things (thread[0])

Comment: `worker1[0].hardware_concurrency()` worker1 is empty when the loop starts. That's an error.

Comment: So you run multiple invocations of function calcMf() and try to spread the calculations over your threads through the usage of the atomic int getXMf? What is with mf? It is shared, too.

Comment: @manni66 i use hardware_concurrency() to get the max threads per System, is this not a good idea to do it like i did?
mf is a part of this zif = (xif - mf) / sf equation.
We only get a vector of x;
mf is defined like this mf = 1/n (x1f + x2f + … + xnf);
i use getXMf oder getXSf to get the the right x of the vector or only use one x[i] one time and not multiple times.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: `worker1[0]` does not exist when the loop starts!

Comment: I know what you mean, but else I coudn't use hardware_concurrency().
worker1.hardware_concurrency(); is not working so i used worker1[0].hardware_concurrency() which works. is this very bad?

Comment: Yes it is wrong. If you have to ask that qeustion you still have to learn the foundation of C++. It's much to early to try multithreading. BTW: what do you want to archive? The calculation would be much faster in one thread with so few values.

Comment: @manni66
yes you are absolutley right at the same time i read a book about c++, but our teacher wants us to do multithreading in c++ only a few of us now c++, most of us now java...
It's a data preparation method for clustering so we should learn it in small steps, but the main topic is paralell computing.

Comment: Re, "most of us know Java."  You'd have the same problem in Java.  You have written code that calls a method of the first object in the `vector`, but you execute that code when the vector does not contain _any_ objects.  That won't work in Java.  That won't work in C++.  That won't work in any  programming language.

Comment: `mf += ...` and `sf += ...` are not atomic operations: Each one happens in three steps.  (1) the CPU reads `mf` or `sf` in from memory, (2) it computes the new value, and (3) it writes the new value back out to memory.  So here's what can happen:  Thread A and thread B both read `mf==5`.  Then, Thread B gets delayed while thread A computes 5+5=10, and stores 10 in `mf`.  Finally, thread B computes 5+7=12 and it stores 12 in `mf`.  The end result?  `mf==12` when the answer you proably wanted was 17.  You need to use a `mutex` to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @jameslarge
now i get what you meant, i created a  "thread mythread" and then i did the hardwareconc...